# What is the performance difference between _.map and _.forEach in Lodash?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, lodash

what is the best way to scroll through a list of _.map and _.forEach in lodash?
I do not need the return value but I only do something inside the loop.

In terms of performance, which is the difference between the two functions?

```
a = []
b = []
list = response._source.carico_scarico
if angular.isDefined(list)
  _.forEach(list, (cs) ->
    if cs.qta >= 0 then a.push cs
    if cs.qta < 0 then b.push cs
  )
```

Or

```
a = []
b = []
list = response._source.carico_scarico
if angular.isDefined(list)
  _.map(list, (cs) ->
    if cs.qta >= 0 then a.push cs
    if cs.qta < 0 then b.push cs
  )
```

Comment: you should do your own performance calculations.

Comment: "In terms of performance" - you need to objectively measure this yourself

Comment: So there is no way to know absolutely if one method is better than the other?

Comment: There's a way to know absolutely for a given use case: Measure it.

Answer (score 8):

> In terms of performance, which is the difference between the two functions?

It's extremely unlikely to matter. If you're worried about it mattering, create a test that's representative of your real code and try it (perhaps on http://jsperf.com). But unless you're dealing with hundreds of thousands of entries, or repeating your loop hundreds of thousands of times, the real-world impact of any difference between them is likely to be nothing. (Heck, with modern JavaScript engines, hundreds of thousands may not even be enough to see a difference you'd care about.)

But speculating: As `map` has to create and populate an array to use as a return value (which you're going to ignore), and `forEach` doesn't, it stands to reason that `map` will be *very very slightly* slower.

---

**But**: The bigger argument here is *using the right tool for the job*: If you don't need the return value, don't use `map`. Its purpose is to create a result by mapping values from the original object into a new one. You don't want that, so `map` is an odd choice, likely to trip up people doing maintenance on the code down-the-line.